# How to find out when to send new Labels to ZPL printers

Tags: java, printing, zpl

For printers from various companies that support ZPL (or some sort of emulation) we need to figure out when we should send new ZPL labels to the printer. The actual print of the label gets triggered by an external signal, so we have to know when a new label should be loaded into the printer buffer.

Currently, we use the *~HS* ZPL command, which returns the labels in the buffer. That is all well and good, but many printers that support some form of ZPL don't support this command, especially the buffer information. An example of this are the Honeywell printers, which supprt ZPl via their Zsim emulation.

The goal here is to use a general ZPL command (not *~HS*) via TCP from a Java application to get information on when the printer needs new labels for printing. Is there a way to find out when the printer is done printing?

Comment: Are you asking "Is there a way to find out when the label media is low or out?"

Comment: The printers have a buffer to save several print jobs. You don't have to wait until a single label is printed!

Comment: I'm still having difficulty understanding what you are asking for.

Comment: @EdHayes3 The printer gets triggered by an external signal. We provide a zpl label. If the printer received a trigger and printed the label we need to know that we should send another one. So yes, the question is, is there a way to find out that the printer is out of labels with data to print. Using ~HS to find out the labels remaining in the printer buffer only works on some printers.

Comment: @DelphiCoder yes, we send multiple labels to the printer buffer. Each print requires a new label. The ~HS command returns the amount of labels currently in the buffer. But that only works on some printers. The question is, is there an alternative way to know when to send new labels.

Comment: It is still not clear, why you need to know this. You just send a job to the printer, done!

Comment: @DelphiCoder because the amount of prints is variable, in theory endless and the data for each print aswell. When you talk about jobs, which ZPL Commands do you mean?

Comment: This still does not explain, why you just not send the data to print to the printer when you get the signal.  Do you fear a full printer buffer or something? I'm not talking about specific ZPL commands, a job is just the label to print.

Comment: @DelphiCoder We dont get the signal, the printer gets a print trigger signal by an automation system. We are just here to supply the data. We dont trigger prints and we dont know when the printer prints. That's why we have to make sure there is always data available to print. A job in this case could be thousands of labels, so a full buffer is indeed a concern. If there is a way to get a message from the printer when it printed, that would help already.

Comment: It's been some time since I've worked with automated printing, but there's specific print head for automated printing. I'm not sure if the other printers allow for it. Likely so. There's probably a setting in the printer that is needed to set. You should then be able to send 100s of labels to the printer through the network. The printer is connected to the automation through serial I believe, and there's a command to "print next label". This should work with discreet or serialized/many quantity print jobs. There should be no need to care what is in the buffer. Zebra support can help you too.

Comment: I guess that seems to be the only option. Wish there was a way to get a notification from the printer when it finishes a print